# App crashes on Tablet rotate, during development phase

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I am developing a web-based Android application using `PhoneGap` and `Eclipse IDE` on *Windows*.
My development's scope is limited to Tablets. More specifically to the *Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1*.

So basically, I develop on Eclipse, and test the app on the Tablet using Eclipse's **Run** command.

Everything works great until i rotate the Tablet. The app crashes.
Therefore I cannot test my `CSS` media queries during this dev phase.

Is there a way to circumvent or fix this behavior ?
*(other than testing the app in Portrait mode, then close it to test it in landscape mode)*

*Note: Using the Android Emulator on Windows is NOT an option.*

> **Phonegap** 1.4
>   **Android** 3.2
>   **Eclipse** IDE for JavaScript Web Developers ( Indigo Service Release 1 )

---

[Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ye9iAkTg) is my app's Log, starting from the moment i rotate the Tablet.

Comment: There is no crash listed in the LogCat. Can you post a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

as your config change parameter in your apps AndroidManifest.xml to
see if it fixes your issue.

I have a Samsung Tab 10.1 and if you don't have the proper configuration changes setup in your manifest your whole app will be reloaded on conf change.

Comment: Thank you! `screenSize` is exactly what i was missing in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what your manifest file looks like. Of the manifest is not your problem, its probably in the assets either your css or js

Do you have: `android:resizeable="true"`

Here is the relevant parts of my manifest that may help:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

And ensure you're building on at least an 4.0 Android SDK otherwise "screenSize" will flag as an error!